# Float Bottom? Positioning divs on the bottom of other divs

Tags: css, html

I'm realizing more and more that I don't have a good understanding of css positioning. Seeing that this often causes problems for me, I've been attempting to create different layouts just for practice. I'm trying to create a website that could hold 6 different divs that display 6 different data points. Two large divs and the top each covering 50% of the screen, 4 smaller divs below each covering 25% of the screen.

I did some research and found that float left would give me the results for the top half, but I can't seem to figure out how to position the the bottom four divs so that they stay flushed with the divs above and to side. Everything that I've tried so far fails whenever I resize the screen. Can someone point me in the right direction please?

here is a pic of what I have so far. The top half is right, the bottom half is what i'm stuck on

[image]

here is my html

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>flatpage</title>


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">

  <div id ="main">

  <div class = "navbar">
  </div>

  <div class =  "total_number_container">
  </div>

  <div class = "searched_number_container">
  </div>

  <div class = "attribute_one>"
  </div>

  <div class = "attribute_two>"
  </div>

  <div class = "attribute_three>"
  </div>

  <div class = "attribute_four>"
  </div>
  </div>

</head>

<body>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my css

```
body {
background-color:#ecf0f1;
margin:0;
}

.navbar{
background-color:#2c3e50;
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

.total_number_container {
background-color:#3498db;
float: left;
width: 50%;
height: 300px;
}

.searched_number_container {
float:left;
background-color:#2980b9;
width: 50%;
height: 300px;
}

.attribute_one {
background-color:#5C97BF;
width: 25%;
height: 300px;
}

.attribute_two {
background-color:#34495e;
width: 25%;
height: 300px;
}

.attribute_three {
background-color:#5C97BF;
width: 25%;
height: 300px;
}

.attribute_four {
background-color:##34495e;
width: 25%;
height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Well, for starters, your HTML in invalid.

Comment: All of your DIV code should be in the BODY. A script tag can be in the BODY or the HEAD - most developers put them either in the HEAD or just before the close BODY tag.

Comment: `<div class = "attribute_two>"` that quote belongs inside the closing `>`, and I'd remove those spaces around the equal sign although I'm not sure they're necessarily invalid.

Comment: Tip: use http://validator.w3.org/ to check your HTML, and http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ to check CSS before trying to figure out if your CSS positioning isn't done right. If either have syntax mistakes then you will be stuck trying to debug something your browser can't understand/display correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fiddle corrects syntax mistakes in the original HTML and CSS code, and uses the original classes (`.attribute_one, .attribute_two, .attribute_three, .attribute_four`) to achieve the desired results.

http://jsfiddle.net/2G8C7/

The key things missing were:

```
.attribute_one, .attribute_two, .attribute_three, .attribute_four {
    float: left;
}
```

And the following HTML syntax mistake:

```
<div class = "attribute_one>" <!-- notice the closing quote is in the wrong place -->
</div>
```

which should be

```
<div class = "attribute_one">
</div>
```

Also there was a typo in the CSS, where the `background-color` for `.attribute_four` had two #'s (`##34495e`)

Answer (score 1):

You mean, something like the below?

This can be achieved using floats and % sizing.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/5Mvm3/2/)

HTML

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
div:nth-child(1), div:nth-child(2) {
    width:50%;
}
div {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid black;
    width:25%;
    height:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <div class = "attribute_one>"
      </div>

      <div class = "attribute_two>"
      </div>
<div class = "attribute_three>"
  </div>

  <div class = "attribute_four>"
  </div>
```

Above is a part from your HTML and is wrong. What you want is

```
    <div class = "attribute_one">
      </div>

      <div class = "attribute_two">
      </div>
<div class = "attribute_three">
  </div>

  <div class = "attribute_four">
  </div>
```

After that just use float:left for all four divs ans set the width to 25%. And after that is a best practice to put another div

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```